# Storing Database in phone memory

Tags: ios, database, cordova

How to store database in phone memory(IOS devices)??

I tried with window.opendatabase concept.. It is stored in browser memory.. but i want to store it in the device memory folder..

window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Demo", 200000);

And also i tried with phonegap app Which is used to store database in phonememory.. But my webpage is in external server.. So accessing device memory from webpages which is in external server, is also probem..

Give some suggestions to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) framework. It's not for the faint of heart, but it's robust and well documented.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. CoreData framework is based on native code of ios.. But i am trying with accessing device memory from external webpage...

Comment: If this is possible, I should sell my iPhones.